# Using Java LocalTime.parse method

Tags: java, time

I am trying to write a simple program in Java.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class test {
   LocalTime openT;
   LocalTime closeT;
    
   public test(String ot, String ct) {

      this.openT = new LocalTime.parse(ot);
      this.closeT = new LocalTime.parse(ct);
  }
}
```

When I hover over .parse NetBeans keeps telling me:

> Cannot find symbol
>
> symbol: class parse
>
> location: class localTime

I searched high and low but I can't figure out what's wrong here...

Anybody can give me some hint?

Thank you.

Comment: LocalTime.parse() is a static method, get rid of the new keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `new` keyword. The parse method is `static`.

Comment: Not sure what it means, I'll look into it. 
But it works, thank you!

Comment: Very short explanation: with `new` you allocate heap space for a new object or easier you create a new object. but there are some methods called functions which don't need a creation of a new object. these methods are marked with the keyword `static`.

Comment: In other words, in Java, “static” means “not object-oriented”. When you have a chunk of code that you want to run without bothering to instantiate an object, you need somewhere to stash that code and give it a name. With no better place available in Java we stick the code in a named method, attach the method to a class, and add a `static` modifier to signify that the method is not intended for objects. We use the class name (`LocalDate`) to find the method (`parse`) and invoke it by the use of the period (`.`). The convention of naming a class with an initial uppercase helps with reading.